# Can the weight matrix for the K-NN graph be substituted for the full kernel matrix in Lap-RLS manifold regularization?

Tags: kernel-trick, manifold-learning

In [this paper](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~niyogi/papersps/BNSaistats.pdf) the algorithm on page 4 describes computing a weight matrix for a data adjacency graph, and a kernel matrix.

I was wondering if it would make sense to substitute the weight matrix for the kernel matrix in order to reduce the amount of memory needed to compute the full kernel matrix.